# Template not found in action method after calling a library method in symfony

Tags: templates, symfony1, action

I'm calling a method of a library that I've created in symfony 1.2. If I don't call the library method in the action method, then the method in the action class works as it should, and it finds the template. But, if I call the library method in the action class, symfony tells me that it cannot find the template associated to the action method. Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you do in this library of yours? maybe the library is messing up symfony's view somehow. otherwise ther shouldn't be any problems with calling your library from action methods.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **return sfView::NONE** on your action code?

Comment: I tried to add this line after I call the library method, but then I get the error: "Rollback failed. There is no active transaction.". I'm not carrying out any transactions...

Comment: Ok, fixed the transaction error... but with 'NONE', the page just displays blank.

Answer (score 0):

Returning sfView::NONE is telling Symfony to display nothing.  The explicit return value sounds like the right approach but you probably want:

```
return sfView::SUCCESS;
```